# NullpointerException when stopService in ServiceTestCase

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-testing, servicetestcase

I am testing my service by using `ServiceTestCase`.

```
public class MyTest extends ServiceTestCase<MyService>{
   private Context mContext;
   private Intent intent;

   public MyTest(){
     super(MyService.class);
   }

   @Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mContext = this.getContext();
    intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
   }

   @MediumTest
   public void runMyTest(){
    startService(intent);
   }

   @Override
   public void tearDown() throws Exception {
     super.tearDown();
     MyService service = getService();

     //line 33, NullpointerException here, why?
     mContext.stopService(intent); 
  }

}
```

But when I run my test, I constantly get **NullPointerException** when call `stopService(intent)` in `tearDwon()` callback. Why?

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.my.app.test.MyTest.tearDown(MyTest.java:33)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Comment: paste your stacktrace please :)

Comment: did you try to set `mContext` and `intent` to be static?

Comment: Are you sure that `startService` is called prior to `stopService` ?

Comment: g00dy , seems my startService isn't called, do you know why??

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `mContext` as `null`.

Try

```
mContext =  getSystemContext();
```

instead of

```
mContext = this.getContext();
```

So that it becomes,

```
@Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mContext =  getSystemContext();

    intent  = new Intent(); // the intent created this way can not be null.
    intent.setClass(mContext , MyService.class);

   }
```

Comment: Aren't they the same? I mean getContext() & this.getContext()

Comment: I m sorry, I should have typed getSystemContext(); Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Hi, I still get null, seems the problem is that my startService() isn't called. Do you know why?

Comment: can you just try once using only getContext() and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getContext() try, getSystemContext();

As per the documentation

> Returns the real system context that is saved by setUp(). Use it to create mock or other types of context objects for the service under test.

Comment: With getSystemContext() I still get null